# How do I call java methods on an object from a FreeMarker template?

Tags: java, freemarker

Is it possible to call a method that takes parameters from a Freemarker template?

I have an object model that I'm trying to render with Freemarker into a web page. One of the objects has a method to get a sublist of it's contents - taking a parameter that is used to filter the list:

`public List getunits(final String type);`

I know in JSP you can't do this directly, but you can write custom functions that will allow you to achieve the result you want. How do you solve this in Freemarker? Is it the same with writing custom functions? Or is there some way of actually calling this kind of function?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

FreeMarker allows invoking methods that were made available through the model from within [expressions](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_methodcall).

Assuming your object has been exposed as `myBean` you can invoke the method as follows:

```
<#list myBean.getunits("myType") as unit>
  do stuff with ${unit}
</#list>
```

You don't have to use `<#list>`, of course, it's just there as an example since your method returns a list.

Comment: Had problems when my bean was extending a TreeMap. It can't find the method in that case.

Comment: @tbraun: You need `?api` in that case. The methods of `Map`-s aren't exposed (with `DefaultObjectWrapper` at least) because in FTL, unlike in Java, the methods don't have their own namespace. So they would mix with the keys in the map, like `myMap.someKey` and `myMap.get` (returns the `Map.get` method) would both return something, and would be both listed with `myMap?keys`, etc. That would be a mess. So by default `myMap.something` only looks for the `something` `Map` key, not the `something` method. But you can work that around like `myMap?api.get(...)`.

Answer (score 24):

As **ChssPly76** said, you can just peform the method call from within a Freemarker template, as long as you expose the object in the model.

But it's important to keep in mind that if your method returns NULL (for whatever reason), you are going to get a confusing

```
Expression myBean.getunits() is undefined on line ....
```

To avoid this, you should better use `myBean.getunits(...)!` (notice the exclamation point).

Learn more about how Freemarker handles nulls here: http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_missing

Comment: Very helpful to know about the `!`.  Also, note that it may be useful to add a default value to the return of the `getunits` method: like this:  `<#list myBean.getunits("myType")![] as unit>`.   In this case, the default is an empty sequence.