# Calling Java class's method from javascript in a freemarker template

Tags: java, javascript, spring-mvc, freemarker

I have a **freemarker** template with **javascript** in it, and I'm using **spring mvc** to pass in a java object "emailer".

Somehow, in this freemarker template, I want to call the emailer object's "sendEmail(params, ..)" method from javascript within the freemarker template. I know how to call java methods from freemarker (the regular way - for example: [How do I call java methods on an object from a FreeMarker template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362343/how-do-i-call-java-methods-on-an-object-from-a-freemarker-template)) , but I don't know how to do it from **within the javascript**.

Is this even possible? If so, how?
And if it's not, what are some alternatives?

The overall goal was to get a value from a dropdown list (using javascript), and then using that value in the java method that gets called when a button is pressed.

Thanks in advance! If more info is needed, I'd be happy to provide it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the only possible combination of how these technologies would work together, but in the usual flow of things, what you're looking forward wouldn't be possible:

- A `Java` call (mediated with `Spring`) renders the `FreeMarker`, allowing calls back into `Java` code as it processes.
- This rendered string (which might happen to contain some `Javascript`) is shipped over `HTTP` to the client browser.  At this point the `Java` execution has completed.
- In the browser, the generated text is parsed, and the `Javascript` is run.  Here there is no direct knowledge of the server, and there is no way to call back that completed thread of control.

So unless you're doing something more unusual, no you can't do what you're suggesting.

There are tools to allow client-side Javascript to call back to the server and to interact with Java there.; so you can rig something up.  But you will not simply call the Java directly without more work.