# Freemarker expressing is undefined

Tags: java, freemarker

I have the below freemarker in a template:

`${root.product.getInventoryReference(channel)}`

When running my application in eclipse it works fine however when i run the compiled version i get the error:

```
Expression root.product.getInventoryReference(channel) is undefined on line 3, column 28 in rtd.integration.builder.ApiOperationConfigurationKeySource@b701440-sourceTemplate.
The problematic instruction:
----------
==> ${root.product.getInventoryReference(channel)} [on line 3, column 26 in rtd.integration.builder.ApiOperationConfigurationKeySource@b701440-sourceTemplate]
----------
```

My product object has the method getInventoryReference as below:

```
public class Product extends ... {
   ...
   public String getInventoryReference(Channel channel) {
    ChannelProduct selectedChannelProduct = getChannelProduct(channel);
    if (selectedChannelProduct != null) {
      return selectedChannelProduct.getInventoryReference();
    }
    return null;
  }
  ...
}
```

I know product, root and channel aren't null because im able to access other methods from root.product within the same template and make use of channel else where.

I have also checked that the product class file in the built version of my application does in fact have the method. Which after de-compiling I can confirm that to be the case.

Does anyone have any other ideas as to why this might be failing?
Thank you

Comment: Just a guess, but it might be the "get" in your "getInventoryReference" method - try  calling ${root.product.inventoryReference(channel)}

Comment: good idea but alas the same error

Comment: Is your selectedChannelProduct null? Then this might be the problem. Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4714553/1842905

Comment: That did it.... thank you!

Comment: To clarify, the error message means that the return value of `getInventoryReference(channel)` was `null`, not something else. As it's visible from the implementation of `getInventoryReference`, it can return `null`. So certainly you should handle that case. What do you want your template to print in that case? You have to tell FreeMarker explicitly what to do then.